# How to identified face from line drawing?

Tags: graph, line-drawing

A line drawing is like a graph but its vertices have x,y position. There are no crossing edges. For example, [a line drawing like this](http://i44.tinypic.com/27xms5u.png) is a line drawing with 13 vertices numbered by 0-12. A face is a cycle that doesn't have a path that 'inside' it. Faces in the example would be

```
(0,1,3,2,0), (2,3,5,4,2), (4,5,8,7,4), (7,8,12,11,7) and (0,2,4,7,11,10,9,6,0)
```

The cycle `(0,1,3,5,4,2,0)` is NOT a face because there is a path that located inside it, named `(2,3)`.  Cycle `(0,1,3,5,8,12,11,10,9,6,0)` is also NOT a face because there is a path (0,2,4,7,11), located inside it. What algorithm can I use to identify faces like the ones in the example?

Answer (score 0):

Assume all your edges are line segments; every planar graph can be drawn using only line segments. Also assume the graph is connected. Now the algorithm is pretty simple:

Construct a directed graph, such that the vertices are same as in the original graph and there's two directed edges for every original edge, one in each direction

Start with a random (directed) edge that's not been used yet. At its end, choose the next outgoing edge clockwise (or counterclockwise will do as well, just always the same). To decide which edge that is, you'll have to compute from the coordinates of vertices in the planar embedding. You'd better precompute this edge order for each vertex beforehand.

Keep doing that with the end of the selected edge, until you reach the starting vertex. At that point, you've completed a face.

When there's no unused edges, you've found all faces in the graph

Or, use a library like Boost, that has an [efficient implementation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/graph/doc/planar_face_traversal.html) of such task